# Simple List Demo

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have made a simple `ListDEmo` in android..with two activity.in **1st** activity 3 edittexts and 2 buttons insert and ,cancel are there...and in **2nd** activity ,there is a `ListView` and a button "back" is there,
Now i want is that when `"Insert"` button pressed..The values of three `EditTexts` should display on `ListView` of other Activity..my code is as below:

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.listdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.R.id;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button b1,b2;
EditText e1,e2,e3;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final EditText e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final EditText e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);


      //  final ArrayList<String> noteList = new ArrayList<String>();
        //final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String s1 = e1.getText().toString();
            String s2 = e1.getText().toString();
            String s3 = e1.getText().toString();
            //Intent i =new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
             Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("edit1", s1);
                i.putExtra("edit2", s2);
                i.putExtra("edit3", s3);
                startActivity(i);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    }



}
```

**SecondActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.listdemo;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.sax.StartElementListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SecondActivity extends ListActivity {
ListView lv;
Button bt;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

          lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            String[] list = new String[3];
            list[0] = getIntent().getStringExtra("edit1");
            list[1] = getIntent().getStringExtra("edit2");
            list[2] = getIntent().getStringExtra("edit3");

            lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,list));


       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), st1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i =new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

please help me frens..! thank you all

Comment: as @Nunu already said you miss to init b1 and b2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to initialize `b1` & `b2`, then in the click listener of `insert` button, read the values from the edit texts, and pass them using the `intent`..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    e2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    e3=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);

    b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);

b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String s1 =e1.getText().toString();
        String s2 =e2.getText().toString();
        String s3 =e3.getText().toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("edit1", s1);
        i.putExtra("edit2", s2);
        i.putExtra("edit3", s3);
        startActivity(i);
    }
});
}
```

in the second activity read the values from the intent, and pass them to the list adapter..

by the way the `back` button action in the second activity, can be simply `finish()`

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String[] list = new String[3];
    list[0] = getIntent().getStringExtra("edit1");
    list[1] = getIntent().getStringExtra("edit2");
    list[2] = getIntent().getStringExtra("edit3");

    lv.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow,list));

    bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            finish();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have done that you told...But can you please tell me how to get in secondactivity and in ListView?

Comment: updated answer, check http://windrealm.org/tutorials/android/android-listview.php

Comment: Link not open sir..!and when i run my application emulator shows error that "your app unfrotunately stoped"...please help me

Comment: @jigar the link provided by Nunu opens easily.

Comment: lv.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.simplerow,list)); displays errors...

Comment: yes as you should put your own layout instead of  R.layout.simplerow

Answer (score 0):

This is really for you. Take it

http://android-mantra.blogspot.in/2013/09/how-to-add-list-items-dynamically-using.html

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("edit1", s1);
            i.putExtra("edit2", s2);
            i.putExtra("edit3", s3);
            startActivity(i);
```

This is correct in first activity.

Next try
this in your second activity then add to list.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
list[0] = b.getString("edit1");
list[1] = b.getString("edit2");
list[2] = b.getString("edit3");
```

I got ur error, Please give the id to button in second activity.
i.e

```
bt=(Button) findViewById(R.Id.button1);
```

Now run the project

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think so its better to see the full code there then typing here. The dynamically list adding is only with a edit text this can be implemented to your project as you wish.